# zsh: indic fonts support rendering issue which is working fine on bash

Tags: zsh, unicode

I am using gnome-terminal 3.36 version
In `bash`  I can type without issues

```
$ अखिल्
```

In `zsh`  it's not showing properly

```
$ अखिल<094d>
```

[image: zsh indic fonts]

this is zsh behaviour for indic fonts which are working fine in bash.

Comment: I don't think this is a font or rendering problem.  Firstly because bash and zsh are different. Secondly because if I copy-paste `ल्` into zsh I too get `ल्<094d>` which I can then back space to leave just `ल्`.  If it were fonts or rendering that backspace would do nothing but remove the whole character.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you run [`info zsh 'special characters'`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#index-special-characters_002c-highlighting) (assuming you have the zsh documentation in info format installed), you'll see:

> Unprintable multibyte characters
>
> This item applies to control characters not in the ASCII range,
> plus other characters as follows.  If the `MULTIBYTE` option is in
> effect, multibyte characters not in the ASCII character set that
> are reported as having zero width are treated as combining
> characters when the option `COMBINING_CHARS` is on.  If the option is
> off, or if a character appears where a combining character is not
> valid, the character is treated as unprintable.
>
> Unprintable multibyte characters are shown as a hexadecimal number
> between angle brackets.  The number is the code point of the
> character in the wide character set; this may or may not be
> Unicode, depending on the operating system.

```
$ unicode $'\u94d'
U+094D DEVANAGARI SIGN VIRAMA
UTF-8: e0 a5 8d UTF-16BE: 094d Decimal: &#2381; Octal: \04515

Category: Mn (Mark, Non-Spacing); East Asian width: N (neutral)
Unicode block: 0900..097F; Devanagari
Bidi: NSM (Non-Spacing Mark)

Combining: 9 (Viramas)
```

So that U+094D character is in that category.

Run

```
set -o combiningchars
```

If you want zle to handle combining characters.

Same applies for the U+0301 combining acute accent in `Stéphane` for instance which zle renders as `Ste<0301>phane` without that option (my preference personally, as I like to be aware that there are actually two characters that make up that `é` instead of the usual U+00E9 pre-composed `é`).